# Is there an embedded, artificial screen environment in the terminal to test out curses programming?

Tags: ncurses

I’d like to create a second, artificial screen where I can send the output of my curses commands so that if something doesn’t work I’m not stuck inside a display I can’t get out of.

I am using the Python curses library.

Is there any way I could configure curses to control a certain display that I can always close with an overriding command?

Answer (score 1):

Start any terminal emulator. If something goes wrong, you can always close the emulator.

If you want to stay entirely inside a terminal, you can use a terminal multiplexer such as [Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux). If something goes wrong, you can always close the window.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect the output to a specific “display”? I am calling curses commands in a live Python shell. But initscr() doesn’t cause a screen to be launched because the Python shell takes precedence over the display. Can I call initscr() and display the screen in splitscreen with the Python shell?

Comment: @PeterElbert Not that I know of. As far as I can tell, both the Python toplevel and the Python curses bindings want to interact with stdin.